# Animation Clip is not playing after mouse click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a gameObject with attached animation component, and have added `animationClip1.anim` with it.

I have the following code

```
public AnimationClip anim;

    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1"))
        {
            GetComponent<Animation>().Play(anim.name);
        }

    }
```

from interface, i have drag and dropped animationClip1.anim to the (above public variable) of the script..

Script is attached to the object.

So when i run the game, i get this error

> The animation state 'animationClip1.anim' could not be played because
>   it couldn't be found!
>       Please attach an animation clip with the name 'animationClip1.anim' or call this function only for existing
>   animations.

Where is the problem, why on mouse click i am getting this error.. Any Idea please ? Thanks

Comment: Is `animationClip1.anim` actually the animationclip or is it just `animationClip1`?

Comment: yes, it is actually animation clip. I have thirdpersoncontroller prefab in the scene. i added animation component and added animationClip to that component. now when i try to play the same animationClip using the above code, its showing the above error. Second i dont find to mark my animationclip as legacy because thirdpersoncontroller not showing any rigged option

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out

```
void Update () {

    if (Input.GetButtonUp(0))
    {
        GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Animation name");
    }

}
```